# JMeter: Is there any way to inject value "Patient_1077,ELLA(161st Pharmacy address)" in a input field

Tags: csv, testing, load, jmeter

I have a a field which accepts value as **"Patient_1077,ELLA(161st Pharmacy address)"** i.e: Patient ID, name and Address, that I want to parameterize, CSV is not helpful in this case as value contains comma itself, is there any alternative way where I can inject these kind of values from file and parameterize the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make values in csv like:

1. Patient_0154, ELLA(102st The Cave)
2. Patient_0155, ELLA(101st The
   Wall)

Then read it:

- Patient_0154 -> user
- ELLA(102st The Cave) -> adress

And when you need the value you do the simple trick — ${user}**,**${adress}.
At least this is my approach when I don't want to code a lot for a simple task.

Comment: That's very smart way to inject values. :)

Answer (score 1):

Delimiter is configurable. See this for an example:

http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/

You can also quote the data, which is another solution in your case.